# Put variable to the request name

Tags: api, postman, newman

Is there some way to put my environment variable to the request name in the Postman?

I have tried this in the request name, but it is not working:

```
Request_name {{my_variable}}
```

Thank you

Comment: That's not possible through the UI as that just a basic string value that doesn't resolve variables like other parts of the app.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the answer.